# Problema al validar un Entry en Tkinter

Tags: python, validación

Buscando por Internet encontré como validar un `Entry` y evitar que el usuario ingrese algún valor que no sea un número, el código es:

```
import tkinter as tk

def validate_entry(text):
    return text.isdecimal()

root = tk.Tk()
root.config(width=300, height=200)
root.title("Mi aplicación")
entry = tk.Entry(validate="key",
              validatecommand=(root.register(validate_entry), "%S"))
entry.place(x=50, y=50, width=150)
root.mainloop()
```

Funciona perfecto, el problema se da cuando intento adecuarlo a mi código que, aunque no da error la función como tal me deja ingresar cualquier carácter y no es lo deseado, mi código es:

```
import tkinter as tk

class nombreclase(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
    self.parent = parent


    self.entry=tk.Entry(validate="key",
                        validatecommand=(self.parent.register(self.validate_entry),"$S")
                        )
    self.entry.grid(row=1, column=0)

def validate_entry(self, text):
    return text.isdecimal()


if __name__=="__main__":
    raiz=tk.Tk()
    nombreclase(raiz).pack
    raiz.mainloop()
```

Agradezco su comprensión y ayuda, gracias!

Comment: Cambia "$S" por "%S"

Comment: Eso era perfecto muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, creo que debes tener cuidado de no usar `isdecimal()`! El tipo del `Entry` es `str`, por lo que obtendrás la siguiente excepción:

```py
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isdecimal'
```

Regresando a la validación como tal, puedes notar en la documentación de Tkinter que el valor de texto a validar es recibido en el tercer argumento, por lo que puedes modificar tu método de validación y el registro del mismo así:

```py
class nombreclase(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        self.entry=tk.Entry(validate="key",
                            validatecommand=(self.parent.register(self.validate_entry), '%d', '%i', '%P')
                            )
        self.entry.grid(row=1, column=0)

    def validate_entry(self, action, index, value_if_allowed):
        if value_if_allowed:
            try:
                float(value_if_allowed)
                return True
            except ValueError:
                return False
        else:
            return False
```